# Slick 3.1 - Printing SQL from DBIOAction (insert statements)

Tags: sql, scala, slick

In Slick 3.1, with the complete redesign of the new API, it seems to be impossible to view the generated SQL statements when doing an insert.

If you have something like this

```
val action = DBIO.seq(
  SomeTables ++= Seq(TableData(1,"First"),TableData(2,"Second"))
)
```

It doesn't seem you are actually able to see the generated SQL from the `action`. The `result` method doesn't actually exist, and variations of `statements` just print `?` in place of the actual values if you don't use `DBIO.seq`, if you are using `DBIO.seq` the `statements` method doesn't actually exist.

Even when using methods such as `.transactionally` or `.withPinnedSession`, it doesn't seem to make a difference (however I don't know how this should help).

From observation of all of the methods, it appears that this is impossible?

Comment: Same here, tried to find a way to print the sql from DBIOAction but with no luck. Hope someone here point us towards correct direction. It prints "?" because it is defaulting to Prepared Statement?

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: there is a way in the documentation : http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#querying

Comment: New feature added to 3.2. and then add to log4j this is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is not handle by Slick 3.1 you can see the [source code](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3.1/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/LoggingStatement.scala), but you can get this feature available into  Slick 3.2 version.

If you a have a larger code base & can't upgrade to 3.2 in that case you can just add [this commit](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3.1/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/LoggingStatement.scala) to 3.1 source code, build & use it. Make sure you import the necessary things required for the commit.